# What muscles would get sore if humans had wings and could fly?

Tags: fantasy-races, flight, winged-humans

I'm intrigued by the idea of humans with feathered wings as a 6th appendage, but with prolonged flight, if such a thing were actually possible for humans naturally as it is in my book, I'm not sure which muscles would become sore over long periods with little rest between, especially for newer fliers, or people unaccustomed to those long distances. As it would be with any other type of muscle fatigue there is the expected amount of soreness and weakness, shaky legs or burning and cramping, but which muscle group would this affect? Feel free to elaborate, anything and everything will help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your back muscles: The lats

Comment: Without a clear picture of what these humans would look like, this question isn't really answerable. If you want bat-like wings, it would be the arm and chest muscles, as well as the heart. However, bat-like wings (or bird-like, for that matter) entail _replacing_ normal human arms with wings, which I suspect isn't what you had in mind. If you want a separate set of wings from the back, like angels, the answer is "whatever muscles you imagine", because our existing muscles wouldn't be able to move such wings: you'd have to invent new ones, and make a lot of other changes to the body as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The muscles would have to be just as imaginary as human wings themselves are, you would need to develop a new set of muscle groups, analogous to those we use for our arms, but with more focus on performance in a single plane (the direction of beating).

In addition to these imaginary muscle groups, your core muscles (Thoracic and abdominal) would likely fatigue as well, not to mention your heart and lungs from the level of activity that would need to be sustained.

You'd also likely have to lighten the skeleton, and that would be very risk from an evolutionary standpoint as humans rely heavily on their strong bones for survival.